# How do I specify custom /res directory in Robolectric 2.2?

Tags: android, robolectric, android-testing

My unit tests and my android app live in separate projects.

With Robolectric 1, I could specify my /res directory location like so:

```
public class MyTestRunner extends RobolectricTestRunner {
    public MyTestRunner(Class<?> testClass) throws InitializationError {
        super(testClass, "../app/AndroidManifest.xml", "../app/res");
    }
}
```

How do I specify the /res directory location in Robolectric 2.2?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`RobolectricTestRunner#getAppManifest(Config)`](http://robolectric.org/javadoc/org/robolectric/RobolectricTestRunner.html#getAppManifest%28org.robolectric.annotation.Config%29):

```
public MyTestRunner(Class<?> testClass) throws InitializationError {
    super(testClass);
}

@Override
protected AndroidManifest getAppManifest(Config config) {
    return new AndroidManifest(
            Fs.fileFromPath("../app/AndroidManifest.xml"),
            Fs.fileFromPath("../app/res"),
            Fs.fileFromPath("../app/assets"));
}
```

Comment: Since Robolectric 2.x, use the [@Config](http://robolectric.blogspot.com/2013/05/configuring-robolectric-20.html) annotation instead.

Comment: @Xian Does `@Config` work with a `gradle` build, when the tests live in `src/test/java`?  Or is `RobolectricGradleTestRunner` still required?

Comment: I'm unclear on why the `gradle` world is so different; sorry, not sure.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same question a while ago, all you have to do is annotate your test class with:

`@Config(manifest = "../app/AndroidManifest.xml")`

and the dependencies will be picked up for you from your manifest.

PS. also make sure you have annotated your test class with `@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)` and your methods with the appropriate JUnit annotations (`@Before`, `@Test`, `@After` etc.) as well (just in case you haven't and forgot).

Comment: Does `Robolectric` then assume that the `res` directory is a sibling of `AndroidManifest.xml` (i.e.: assumes that `res` is in `../app`)?

Comment: Yep, by default it looks for `res` and `assets` relative to the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Note that you can also [specify project-wide config settings](http://robolectric.blogspot.com/2013/05/configuring-robolectric-20.html) like the manifest in `src/test/resources/org.robolectric.Config.properties`:
`manifest=../app/AndroidManifest.xml`