# Robolectric: how fix FileNotFoundException from assets?

Tags: android, robolectric, android-testing

In my robolectric tests I am trying to read a file. Since this file contains just the test data I have put it in assets of the tests.

The directory structure looks like this.
src/main/assets/prod_data_file
src/test/assets/test_data_file

However when I try to read the file by getShadowApplication().getAssets().open(MY_FILE_PATH) or context.getAssets().open(MY_FILE_PATH) it gives me FileNotFoundException.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

I try this solution [Using assets in robolectric tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24631428/using-assets-in-robolectric-tests/24650394#24650394)

this not work https://stackoverflow.com/a/21465230/1654690

Comment: have you put file directly to assert directory or any sub directory ?

Comment: @HareshChhelana I know diff, any way not work

Comment: Could be a build configuration issue as well. Are you building with gradle or ant? Can you share the build config?

Comment: @AlexFlorescu http://pastebin.com/HDiZ1Rdh

Comment: That looks ok. What path are you trying to open (i.e. whats the value of MY_FILE_PATH)?

Comment: @AlexFlorescu "clear_load/task_list_clear.txt". It correct path

Answer (score 1):

This solution works for me:

1. Move all text files to `src/test/resources` folder
2. Get them with the following code

   ```
   getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("path/inside/resource_folder");
   ```

This [comment](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/2065#issuecomment-148128155) from Robolectric github helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the path is correct. If you are sure the path is correct then  try this ,

Right click the project > click Refresh. It may work. :)